# Is there a way of compiling (i.e. caching) a cupy RawKernel before calling it?

Tags: cupy

I'm writing a python application that processes a lot of images.
The computation speed of the application is important, thus I'm trying to minimize the execution time by writing cupy kernels.

For the sake of simplicity, assume that I have a cupy raw kernel below.

```py
import cupy as cp


add_kernel = cp.RawKernel(r'''
extern "C" __global__
void add_one(float* dimg, float* y) {
    int j = threadIdx.x;
    int i = blockIdx.x;
    int k = blockDim.x;
    int tid = k*i+j;

    y[tid] = dimg[tid] + 1;
}
''', 'add_one')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    h, w = 192, 256
    dimg_cp = cp.zeros(shape=(h, w), dtype=cp.float32)
    y = cp.zeros(shape=(h, w), dtype=cp.float32)
    add_kernel((h,), (w,), (dimg_cp, y))
    print(y)
```

Here, 'add_kernel' simply copies an input matrix and add one to every element of the copied matrix then return it. It works great but I believe the code can be further optimized in terms of execution speed.

According to the [link](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.RawKernel.html), when the kernel is called for the first time (i.e. not cached), there will be an overhead for compilation.

I want to avoid this compilation time.
So I want to ask if there is a way of compiling cp.RawKernel prior to calling the kernel for the first time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no explicit way to precompile the kernel without calling it. One easy solution is just calling it once with a small input. Note that the compiled kernel is also cached to a file, so the overhead only exists at the first execution of the script in the environment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

Yes, I found 'cp.cuda.compiler.compile_with_cache()' instead (which does not use kernel but string template) and am using it instead to precompile it.

I appreciate your clarification.